# How to wirte a variable to database and retrieve it with IBM BPM?

Tags: variables, db2, designer, business-process-management

I am working with IBM BPM Designer and want to create a simple process that is connected to my database.

All my variables up to now were just connected to the process so I did not need to access them from the database. Now here is what I want to do as a test project.

Start process and have a user enter a name in the coach, when he submits the name, the system service checks the database if there is already an entry of that variable with the same name. If there isn't it saves that name in in the database. If there is it checks it it has another attribute called "dateOfBirth"
and displays it.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

IBM BPM is not designed to be used as a System of Record (SoR).  So yes if you want to see this data outside the process context you need to write it somewhere, and for 99% of the cases "somewhere" = "to a database".

You will need a custom table (or tables) to hold your data.  These should be created in a different DB/Schema than the BPM product databases.  That is don't create them in the same space that IBM uses for their product code.

Once you have created your DB Table you need to create a JDBC connection on WebSphere to be able to access that database.  (Unless your JDBC connection for the IBM BPM databases can also access this one).

Now that we have a place for your data to live and a way to connect to that place, we simply need to create the SQL statements to save the data off.  In the System Data Toolkit their are a number Integration Services intended to be used to execute SQL commands.  Pick the one that best matches your need and add it to your service.  Some notes about this -

1)  You should use parameterized queries so as to avoid SQL-Injection attacks.

2)  If you are pulling data to populate a list of  Simple Business Objects (An objects containing only simple types) if you write your query so the column names match the member names in the BO, you can have the connector do the marshaling of the data into the object structure for you.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps I am missing something, but it sounds like you need to use an ajax service to test the database and a simple visibility rule to show or hide the date of birth field. Basic service (8.5.7 release) would look like this.[image]